# When should I call wrapper.update()?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I read the documentation about [.update()](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/update.html), the doc says:

> Syncs the enzyme component tree snapshot with the react component tree. Useful to run before checking the render output if something external may be updating the state of the component somewhere.

But it's not clear. What I don't understand is "something external may be updating". What does "something external" mean?

From the example, it seems the properties of the class-based component are the external thing and we want to change and render them.

Is there any other situation?